# ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial @patients/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have  haml page. i want to render partially index.haml page on that haml page.
can any one give me the right syntax?
the piece of code is :

```
.tab-content
  #tab1.tab-pane.active
    .span6      
      = render  '@patients/index'
```

Comment: what is the name of this view file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `= render 'patients/index` or simply `= render 'index`

which one works depends which page you are rendering this in.  for example, if your file tree looks like this:

```
views
  patients
    index
    show
    etc
  doctors
    index
    show
    etc
```

If the view code above is from `patients/show` and you're rendering `patients/index`, you can use `= render 'index' because you're already inside the`patients`folder.  if the view code you showed were in`doctors/show`, however, then you'd need to specify the parent folder by using`= render 'patients/index'

Comment: i am rending index from haml page which one i was created but in patients views only. with using above line. application give an error :Missing partial patients/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb,......

Comment: what about `= render 'index` ?

Comment: i giving an error: Missing partial patients/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :h